# Pyinstaller onefile doesn't work on other computers

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

My role at work includes automating several processes which are easily automated via Python, for use by the entire team at the office. None of my coworkers have Python set up on their devices (we're all Windows) nor would they be comfortable using it if they did, so I've been compiling my work into .exe files with tkinter.

My most recent (and, of course, the most important) program compiles into a onefile .exe without issue, and runs perfectly on my computer. My coworkers are able to open it and load files into it, but when they go to activate some of the tkinter buttons within, one coworker has absolutely nothing happen while another gets a windows error message that the program has crashed. I'm unable to recreate these issues on my side.

The .exe was made using pyinstaller in a virtual environment, in which I installed all necessary dependencies. The script does not need to read or reference any other files in order to run. Is it possible that the .exe is still somehow missing a dependency that it's finding on my device and not others? How can I be sure? Would setting it up to include an installer wizard make a difference? Thanks for the help on this!

I can't include the full script due to character limit, but I've included the opening lines with all imports.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft as fft
from scipy.fft import ifft as ifft
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import filedialog
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
```

Comment: Hard to tell what is happening. Did you properly set up logging for all errors and stuff being raised? That would be a good place to start. Also onefile is noted to be extremely difficult to debug. so perhaps do it without the onefile setting and then troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Without the onefile setting, I would need to send all of the supporting files produced by pyinstaller to my coworkers as well, yes?

Comment: Only the files in the dist folder. And if your coworkers are not interested in the application backend they probably will never opend the dist folder. just make a shortcut to the exe and it can launch from there.

Comment: Even if you make a onefile with all these imports, it will take atleast 2 minutes to load the app alone.

Comment: Thanks @JasonChia, I'll give it a try. And Cool Cloud: surprisingly, the .exe opens in about fifteen seconds and runs great, I was very impressed.

Comment: Update: I created the .exe without onefile, and without the windowed option. The program still has the same issue for my coworkers; The tkinter interface opens up and runs well, they can load and select files to use, but when they go to initiate one of the functions via tkinter button, the program crashes without an error message. This doesn't happen when I run the program. Surely this means there's a dependency that pyinstaller simply isn't catching?